# Cant get fscanf to perform correctly in simple program

Tags: c, scanf

I keep getting a Seg fault on line 51 `fscanf(fp, "%d", lenPtr)`. Everytime I run the program, "1" is printed, but it never gets to 2 before seg faulting. I have done this many times, and cannot seem to figure out the trouble. I know it is incorrect, but when I replace line 51 with `fscanf(fp,"%d", *lenPtr);`, it doesn't cause a segmentation fault.

```
//Brendan Sullivan
//Section D
//Prelab 5

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum {
    PENNY   = 1,
    NICKEL  = 2,
    DIME    = 10,
    QUARTER = 25,
} Denomination;

typedef struct {
    Denomination denomination;
    int quantity;
} Coin;

typedef Coin *PiggyBank;

PiggyBank loadBank(const char *filename, int *lenPtr);
int totalMoney(PiggyBank bank, int length);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *length;
    PiggyBank piggyBank = loadBank(argv[1], length);

    /*for (i = 0; i < (*lenPtr); i++) {
            printf("%d %d", piggyBank[i].denomination, piggyBank[i].quantity);
    }*/
    return 0;
}

PiggyBank loadBank(const char *filename, int *lenPtr) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened\n");
        *lenPtr = 0;
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("1\n");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", lenPtr); //Line 51
    printf("2\n");
    printf("%d\n", *lenPtr);
    PiggyBank piggyBank = malloc(sizeof(Coin) * (*lenPtr));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < *lenPtr; i++) {
        fscanf(fp,"%u %d", &piggyBank[i].denomination, &piggyBank[i].quantity);
    }
    return piggyBank;
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code with line numbers.  It is less readable and prevents cut and pasting to an editor for testing ans compiling.

Comment: `return piggyBank;
    fclose(fp);` -- `fclose` will never be executed. Move it before the `return`. And `free(piggyBank)` from `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `loadBank` with a uninitialized `int* length` as the destination pointer.  Undefined behavior ensues.  You should instead to this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, length;
    PiggyBank piggyBank = loadBank(argv[1], &length);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", piggyBank[i].denomination, piggyBank[i].quantity);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the code in `loadBank` does not allocate anything and returns an undefined variable `piggyBank` in the middle of the function.  Either your code does not compile or you are not posting it correctly.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I was missing a bit of code there but i made the neccesary edits. When I add the address operator and compile with -Werror and -Wall, I get 
"warning: passing argument 2 of loadBank from incompatible pointer type", followed by a segmentation fault after attempting to run.

Comment: You must change the the of `length` in `main` to `int length;`.  Do you invoke the program with a command line argument for the name of the file?

Comment: Sadly changing `int *length;` to `int length;` didn't help either. I have passed `length` to functions in many programs in a similar fashion with no issues, I just can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: @BCSullivan: did you replace your `main` function with mine instead of patching yours?

Comment: I just retried replacing the main, and it did indeed work. I highly appreciate it. While I do understand why this works, I still do not understand why my code did not -- I've used my method in other programs with no errors.

Comment: @BCSullivan: in your code, you define `length` to be a pointer to `int` but you do not initialize it to point anywhere. dereferencing it to read or write the value invokes undefined behavior. The `int` needs to be somewhere.  In `main` as a local variable is the correct place.